# ¿Como detectar con un Evento en Laravel si un registro de mysql se completa en varios campos por varias peticiones asincronas?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo varias peticiones que hacen update a un mismo registro de una base de datos mysql en forma asincronica (en tiempos diferentes). El registro tiene 5 campos de texto (aparte del `id`, etc) que se van completando en forma separada por estas distintas peticiones.

Pregunta: ¿Hay alguna forma de que Laravel detecte que ese registro ya tiene los 5 campos actualizados (no uno , ni dos, ni tres, sino los 5 ya completos, es decir que ya llegaron todas las peticiones y no falta ninguna) y ahi se dispare un metodo de un controlador?

Comment: se me viene a la cabeza es que cuando hagas los diferentes updates, hagas una consulta sobre ella misma y a ese array lo recorres y miras que campos llegan vacios o null...

Comment: si, pero eso seria la forma tradicional, mi consulta es si posible realizar esto con Eventos y Listeners utilizando Laravel. En la documentacion es posible disparar un evento al modificar el registro, y verificar por un campo en particular con isDirty, que detecta si el modelo ha cambiado y devuelve un booleano, true si hay cambios, false no los hay.

Comment: En codigo seria algo asi:  if($user->isDirty('email')) { //si ha cambiado el correo

Comment: Pero como yo necesito controlar el update de 5 campos y no se cual se llena primero (ahi esta el tema).

Comment: entonces te tocaria validar los 5 al mismo tiempo

Comment: si, el tema es que las peticiones son asincronas, puede que yo valide al segundo 3 , me indique false y al segundo 4 lleguen las 5 peticiones completas, lo que me obligaria a volver a validar de alguna manera, para detectar en la segunda validacion lo que no valide en la primera.

Comment: Hay un tema de tiempos también a considerar, porque las peticiones no llegan todas juntas, de ahi el tema de buscar un Listener, que detecte cuando llego la última.